# AddHandler for custom controls error visual studio

Tags: vb.net, controls, mouseenter, addhandler

I have a MouseEnter event which currently handles some custom controls on my form. The program is a card game. I have a collection (handCards) that gets populated when the user draws a card and then it adds the latest card to the form. This collection holds cards of various custom types, all which inherit from picturebox. Drawing the cards from the deck and adding them to the form works fine. The trouble I am having is that at runtime, after a card is drawn and added to the form, I've created an addhandler line of code to have those cards respond to my MouseEnter event, but my addhandler line of code is telling me that MouseEnter is not an event of object. How can I get around this so that after a card is drawn and added to the form, when the mouse enters the new custom control, my MouseEnter event fires? Here's one of the many things I've tried and what I think should be the simplest and easiest that should work.

```
deck.DrawCard()
AddHandler handCards(handCards.Count).MouseEnter, AddressOf Cards_MouseEnter
```

P.S. the MouseEnter event works fine for custom controls that are on the form prior to runtime and all it does is take the image of the control and enlarge it by placing the image to a bigger card on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I fixed it, in case anyone comes across this post. Made a separate Sub to do the AddHandler. After the program draws a card, it calls upon this method, which then adds the MouseEnter handler I need. The ByVal was key. I originally thought I was supposed to use ByRef, but no. MouseEnter is an event of control, but apparently not Object, so now it works.

```
Public Sub addHandlers(ByVal inputObject As Control)
    AddHandler inputObject.MouseEnter, AddressOf Cards_MouseEnter
End Sub
```

Comment: If your handCards array is still of type `Object` then this is not a good idea because the object you pass to `addHandlers` will be implicitly converted to type `Control`. You can add any object to an array whose references are of type `Object` since every object descends from type `Object`. But, if you add something that does not descend from `Control` to the handCards array and then you pass that to your addHandlers method you will get a runtime exception when the implicit conversion fails. You may say that will never happen, but implicit type conversion is generally considered a bad idea.

Comment: Your compiler settings may ignore implicit conversions but personally I think it is a good idea to change the setting to at least warn about implicit conversions.

Comment: hmmm, not sure how to do that or find that setting. I'm kind of just learning as I go. Think I should put a try catch in there? I really dont ever think any of the cards in the deck (which all inherit from PB) will not work with the addhandler message, but best to be safe, I suppose.

Comment: To change compiler settings go to your project properties, compile tab, and change the "Notification" for the "Implicit Conversion" condition. Better to keep exception handling for unexpected cases, and to avoid exceptions where you can. For instance in my answer I added code to check for a last element of `Nothing` or a zero count array. Similarly it is better to get your types correct, rather than relying on exception handling. You can do this simply by changing the type of your array to `PictureBox` as in my answer, or a suitable Interface type if your objects don't share a common ancestor.

Answer (score 1):

I am supposing your handCards Collection is an Object Collection. Try casting it to the proper type using [CType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb.aspx), something like this:

```
AddHandler CType(handCards(handCards.Count), PictureBox).MouseEnter, AddressOf Cards_MouseEnter
```

as @Jason mentioned using the `handCards.Count` as an index will not work because it is the total number of items where as your index is zero based and will be one less than the Count.
so `handCards(handCard.Count)` should be `handCards(handCards.Count -1)`

Comment: Casting it may have worked, but I got it figured out and posted the solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @clanier9 glad you figured it out. The casting would have worked since your cards are based on PictureBox.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generic collection to avoid type casting.

```
Private handCards As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of PictureBox) _
    = New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of PictureBox)(52)
```

**Or** you could just use an array of `PictureBox` objects

```
Private handCards(5) As PictureBox
```

Remember that you'll have to initialise the collection or array though, by assigning a `PictureBox` object to each element of the array.

Now you can add the handler to a `PictureBox` element of the array since `PictureBox` derives from `Control` which implements the `MouseEnter` event.

```
deck.DrawCard()
If handCards.Count > 0 andAlso handCards.Last() IsNot Nothing then
    AddHandler handCards.Last().MouseEnter, AddressOf Cards_MouseEnter
End If
```

Your handler will look something like this

```
Private Function Cards_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) As Object
    ' Handle mouse events here
End Function
```

Comment: handcards is a Collection that starts at index 1. I actually did try to do a loop through the collection and add the handler that way, but it didn't work either (same error). I did get it working, though, and posted the solution below. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @clanier9 The array index point is incidental. More important is that in your question, you're adding the handler for the item at index `handCards.Count`, which is probably not what you want. The real main point though is about type and inheritance. In your question you are trying to access the `MouseEnter` event from an `Object` reference. Since `MouseEnter` is defined on the `Control` class you need a reference of `Control` or one of it's subclasses, such as `PictureBox` which I suggested since you said all your objects descended from that.

Comment: @clanier9 In the question you said 'This collection holds cards of various custom types, all which inherit from picturebox'. That also sounds like you may run into problems with multiple inheritance, in which case (and as a general rule), you may want to consider using [Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e2e18x.aspx) rather than sub-classes. Or in the words of the [GoF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) "Program to an interface, not an implementation".

Comment: @Jason S - I do want the handler to add the item at index handcards.Count because that is the last card drawn, since each card drawn gets added to the handcards Collection. What kind of problems can arise from multiple inheritance? I just needed a way of creating a PictureBox which could store different custom variables while retaining all of the properties of a picturebox, and that was the only way I knew how to do it. Interfaces look confusing and wouldn't I still need inheritance inside each one?

Comment: @clanier9 Sorry my guess about the index was wrong.  
An interface would allow you to use multiple types that may not even inherit from each other as the parameter type to your method. You may find the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) clearer on these concepts than the MS documents (I do). There is a bit about multiple inheritance at the bottom of that page. Also see [Using an interface as a type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html). Not possible to explain all this in this comment.

Comment: @clanier9 I updated my answer to reflect that you want the last element. Did you try changing your `handCards` array (of type `Object`) to a different type such as `PictureBox`? That ensures that you can only assign objects to this array that are of type `PictureBox` or its subclasses. With your array of type `Object`, you could assign any object, one that may not be a sub-class of your `Control` parameter in `addHandlers` in which case you will get a run-time exception. Exception handlers should catch the unexpected. Better to prevent exceptions than lazily using exception handling everywhere

Answer (score 1):

Luckily I was working around and I managed to do successfully this solution.

First Add Event Handler Method Where ever you Wish, For Test I have added this Function at Button_Click

```
addHandlers(Label1) 'Label one is the control on which I have to attach Mouse Events (Enter,LEave)
```

Now "addHandlers" function implementation

```
 Public Sub addHandlers(ByVal obj1 As Control)
    AddHandler obj1.MouseEnter, AddressOf MouseEventArgs
    AddHandler obj1.MouseLeave, AddressOf _MouseLeave
 End Sub
```

Now the Mouse Events:

```
Private Function _MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) As Object
    Try
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Function

Private Function MouseEventArgs(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) As Object
    Try
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Hand
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Function
```